# Django render template in a pop-up

Tags: javascript, django, popup

As a beginer with javascript, I am looking for a manner to render a template from django in a javascript popup. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create view and django template and in django template create link to new page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'{{title}}','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>

<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('/example/popup')"
    >{% trans 'Link to popup' %}</a>
```

so you must have another app with `'/example/popup'` url

ps: there are many other way ... its only one suggestion!

Comment: @efazati I'm intrested in doing the same as Method , but Your reply is opening a new window, how can I just open a popup in the same window?

Comment: @astrocybernaute javascript dosent something like this by defualt ... i think you must use modals or prompt see links: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals jQuery Impromptu -> http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/  Top 10 jQuery Modal Box Plugins | web enavu -> http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/